# Cloud Firestore REST API permissions denied

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am using Firebase for my project and I bsolutely love it.  My particular setup:

G Suite (for the business)
Firebase (Auth & Data Store)

The issue I am running into is around the REST API.  Right now my configuration is wide open on the DB right now, specifically for testing purposes.

I have an API key created.  I've used the API Explorer and I was able to get access to the DB through OAuth, however, when I try with the API Key (preferred), I get this message:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "Missing or insufficient permissions.",
    "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED"
  }
}
```

I'm calling the endpoint like this:

```
https://firestore.googleapis.com/v1beta1/projects/MY_PROJECT_NAME/databases/(default)/documents/PATH_TO_DATA/key=AUTO_GENERATED_API_KEY
```

DB RULES:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write:  if request.auth != null || request.auth == null;
    }
  }
}
```

Now, I'm sure there's an easy fix for this, but I can't for the life of me figure out why this is happening.  Is there something I need to ensure that is set up in the **"APIs & Services"** area? Do I need to set up something in the project credentials?   I've gone through the documentation and found myself in a feedback loop.

I am really at a loss.  ANY help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

-A

Comment: You have two choices for authenticating with the Firestore REST API, and neither of them involve passing an "API key" of any sort in the URL. https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/use-rest-api#authentication_and_authorization If you're not using Firebase Auth to authenticate the end user, then you have to use oauth with a service account (the second choice on that page).  If you do that, then security rules aren't in play at all - they will be completely skipped.

Comment: @DougStevenson Thank you SO MUCH for your response.  I get what you are saying.  I am using FB Auth to authenticate the user (web).  The Middleware is making the request to Firestore to request data from the DB.  That's where I get stuck.  There's some heavy lifting the MW has to do before it reaches the client.  So with that, I should use the service account?

Comment: If you need to auth with Firebase, then you have to pass along a Firebase Auth ID token to the REST API as described in that documentation.

Comment: @AddamDriver did you find any solution ?